# Enquanto a opção não for um inteiro em C

Tags: c

Queria fazer uma condição no while se o usario digitar uma string .

```
int main()
{
    int opt;

    printf("Escolha um numero do 1 ao 5: \n");
    scanf("%d", & opt);
    
     ***While (opt is not num)
    {
       printf("Escolha um numero do 1 ao 5: \n");
       scanf("%d", & opt);
    }***

    
    switch(opt)
    {
        case 1:
            printf("você digitou o 5");
            break;
```

Comment: `scanf` retorna um int. Use. É para isso.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

O usuário vai digitar alguns bytes; se o seu programa vai lê-los como caracteres, números inteiros, fracionários, ou mesmo uma `struct` personalizada, cabe exclusivamente a você determinar. Então não tem como saber se o usuário digitou um `int` ou um `char`. Uma opção que você teria é ler a entrada como um caractere e testar se ela faz parte do conjunto de entradas aceitas (1, 2, 3, 4 ou 5). Se for um desses caracteres, então converta-os e faça o que tem que ser feito; se não, encerre o programa.

Claro que a sugestão do @arfneto é mais sofisticada. Como o `scanf` retorna o número de caracteres lidos com sucesso, você, como usuário, pode ir entrando valores de 1 a 5 e quando quiser parar, basta apertar enter sem texto nenhum (enviar uma string vazia). Desse jeito: `while (scanf("%c", &opt))`.

Answer (score -1):

Acredito que seria interessante você verificar isso com o IF.

Coloque o conteúdo digitado pelo usuário dentro de uma outra variável e verifique se é *num*, se não for é false e avise ao usuário.